# Magento run custom script on product details page load

Tags: javascript, php, magento-2.3

I’m pretty new to Magento custom modules and just want to be pointed in the right direction to read up on things.

I’m creating a few websites that I want to have stock dynamically updated from an API (that I’m developing).

Currently I have a script that runs every day to update every product with the current stock count, and another script that gets the difference since the last update and does it (every 10minutes).

I don’t like it as there is still room for error and it just doesn’t sit right with me. What I would like is as you click on the product, it makes an API call, updates my custom field, and renders the page. I also have a custom stock status plugin so I really need it to do the call before page load. . I can write some logic on timeout to render the page anyway if there is a problem with the API.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event/Observer feature to call the API. Try one of the following events:-

```
catalog_controller_product_init_before
catalog_controller_product_init_after
catalog_controller_product_view
```

Comment: Thanks thats got me further, I now have other issues - but I've started a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working... Thanks for your help, there is still some work to do, but its calling the script at the correct time! Thankyou

Events.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_controller_product_init_after">
        <observer name="Apicall" instance="Olisco\Tpcconnector\Observer\ApiCall" />
    </event>
</config>
```

```php
<?php
namespace Olisco\Tpcconnector\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ApiCall implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
      #Code here to execute!
    }
}
```